# Allow user to change password Cakephp 2

Tags: passwords, cakephp-2.0

I've looked over various approaches, and various questions published on this subject, but with no luck. In my case, the controller code "appears" to work, and the message flashes up "Your changes have been saved", but the password database field is unchanged. Is there something I am missing?

Controller code

```
public function changepass($id = null) {
    $this->layout = 'profile_page';
    //$this->request->data['User']['id'] = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');

    $user = $this->User->find('first', array( 
        'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
    ));     // 'User.id' => $id
    $this->set('user',$user);


    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))
    {   
        $this->User->saveField('password', AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['newpass']));
        // $this->User->saveField('password', $this->data['User']['password']);
        // $this->data['User']['password']= $this->request->data['User']['newpass'];

        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data))
        {   
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your password has been changed!'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'articles','action'=>'index'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Whoops! Something went wrong... try again?'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'changepass'));
        }
    }
    $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
    unset($this->request->data['User']['password']); // tried commenting out
}
```

Model

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['newpass'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['newpass']);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Of course later I'd put in existing password check, and confirm new password check, but i need to get the existing password update basic approach working.

### Many thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this,

I think I've sussed this. First, major bloop on my part - in my view I'd put echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'edit')); -- of course change action to 'changepass'

New Controller code:

```
    public function changepass ($id = null) {
    $this->layout = 'profile_page';
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
            //debug($this->request->data);

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $this->data['User']['password']= $this->request->data['User']['newpass'];
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your password changes have been saved'));
             $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
         }
    } else {
                if ($this->Auth->user('id')!= $id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('You are not allowed that operation!');
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'index'));
        }

        $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);  
        debug($this->request->data);
        unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
    }
}
```

Model - tidied up as per advice from eboletaire

```
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']); 
    }
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['newpass'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['newpass']);
    }

return true;
}
```

Comment: Why are you saving the password twice??? First you save it with `$this->User->saveField` and later with `$this->User->save($this->request->data)`

Comment: Just been trying out various different alternatives. If I change the save field and put instead $this->data['User']['password']= $this->request->data['User']['newpass']; , still the field is not updated.

Comment: Your code looks quite in a bit of mess,If you are using saveField first you need to load the object with it's id.i.e.$this->User->id =$id(the primary key of the User table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are saving the password twice. Remove/comment this line:

```
$this->User->saveField('password', AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['newpass']));
```

Anyway, I think the problem is in your model. Check out your beforeSave method. Why are you setting password first with field password and then with field newpass???

PD. Cleaning up your code I've also seen that maybe the second if should be outside the first one.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments I have edited out that line, but to no effect :(  The beforeSave method is there for field password for new users..

Comment: Try to leave your methods absolutely clean (commenting the other parts of code). Comment your beforeSave method on the model and your saveField in the controller. Then try to save. The password stores correclty? (of course it should be stored plain). If the password does not store correctly, then add a "debug($this->request->data)" before your $this->User->save. Ensure that you are receiving the password with it's fieldname correctly. Ensure that the fieldname is the same of the DB..

Comment: With a combination of a couple of your tips, and finding my own mistakes, now got this working. So I'll enter this as accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    $this->data['User']['password']= $this->request->data['User']['newpass'];
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
```

Should be

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    $this->data['User']['id'] = $id;
    $this->data['User']['password']= $this->request->data['User']['newpass'];
    if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
```

Watch out for `$this->data` vs `$this->request->data`.